# os.system() returns error code 32512 - Python

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I am using the following system command in Python 2.7. I am able to execute the same command in terminal successfully whereas I am not able to run it in python(getting return code = **32512**). The command basically converts a mp3 file into a wave file along with stereo to mono conversion. I am able to run the same command in terminal successfully.

Below is the command I'm trying out:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i /Users/krish/audio.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 /Users/krish/converted_audio.wav")
```

I also tried using the subprocess command but it gave the same **32512** return code.

Could anyone help me out on what's wrong with this?

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems like python can't find `ffmpeg` in your $PATH. It should work if you use the full path to the ffmpeg executable in your command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more specific answer to this.

Instead of using the command like this in python:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i /Users/krish/audio.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 /Users/krish/converted_audio.wav")
```

First try to find out where is your ffmpeg installation by giving the following command in terminal (Works on linux and mac)

`which ffmpeg`

In my case this was the output of the above command:

`/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`

Now, modify the `os.system` command in python as follows:

```
os.system("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/krish/audio.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 /Users/krish/converted_audio.wav")
```

which should work great without throwing `32512` error!

Comment: yes! you save my life, bro! i thought it was the working dir's problem, but in fact it's the problem of a binary's path!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you have to use the full path to the ffmpeg command with `os.system()`.

Instead of `os.system()` look at `subprocess.call()`.  [This](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators) may help.

Comment: I used the subprocess.call as follows: subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i /Users/krish/audio.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 /Users/krish/converted_audio.wav',shell=True) . Now I get a return code of 127

Comment: You need to read the documentation of subprocess.call.  the link I provided should help.  You have to separate the command and the arguments.

Comment: Thank You. I tried it out separately too. But didn't work. Would be great if you could tell me the exact usage! However, I was able to make it work when i used the full path of ffmpeg in os.system(). In order to retrieve the full path of ffmpeg, I used "which ffmpeg" in the terminal.

Comment: _"you have to use the full path to the ffmpeg command"_ That is simply not true. Both `os.system` and `subprocess` work with just the name of the command.

Comment: Rawing - you're correct.  After further research, 32512 is apparently an error when there are too many characters in the given command.  Was listed as a (closed) bug in 2013 as per: https://bugs.python.org/issue19015  however other research shows that often 32512 throws with 512 which is a 'command not found' error which means the full path is required in that instance.  Otherwise, I assume you're correct.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and I believe you are correct. on the character limit. I was trying to call awk  to build ~370,000 txt files for a larger pipeline and found that `os.system()` works if I loop through each command individually, but not if I bundle all the commands into one long string as input.