# Unable to execute ffmpeg command in terminal through Automator and Python

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, subprocess, automator

I am trying to execute a ffmpeg command in terminal based on information passed through from an Automator workflow as arguments in a python script, located in a PyCharm venv, if that makes any sense?

I have tested the script below in a PyCharm venv and have no issues, but once I change the input to accept the arguments passed through Automator, which are absolute paths to the mp4 files, ffmpeg doesn't seem to want to run.

ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```

python script, involving user input:

```
filename = input() #absolute path to a mp4 file.

new_name = re.search('(.*)\.mp4$', filename).group(1) + '-temp.mp4'
subprocess.run(f"ffmpeg -i '{filename}' -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy '{new_name}'", shell=True)
```

python script, involving arguments from Automator - where arguments are passed in correctly:

```
for filename in sys.argv[1:]: #absolute path to a mp4 file(s), as passed through by Automator
    new_name = re.search('(.*)\.mp4$', filename).group(1) + '-temp.mp4'
    subprocess.run(f"ffmpeg -i '{filename}' -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy '{new_name}'", shell=True)
```

I have tried os.system as well, and have no issues running it when providing user input, but still having the same issues as above, when trying to get Automator to pass any arguments.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you [edit] to provide a representative traceback of the error you get when you run from Automator?

Comment: @tripleee, I am quite the beginner, so not exactly sure how I'd be able to get that setup, but I've tried running the python script under Automator using #!/usr/local/bin/python3 and received the following: (1/2)

Comment: The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “-: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `new_name'
-: -c: line 3: `    new_name = re.search('(.*)\.mp4$', filename).group(1) + '-temp.mp4''” (2/2)

Comment: I solved the issue. I needed to specify the path of ffmpeg which was /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg. 

Solution was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484152/os-system-returns-error-code-32512-python